# Loudspeaker detected yet won't connect

Tags: speakers, bluetooth-speaker

Laptop Dell E5430
Running Ubuntu 16.04
Speaker Unotec Bullet sound
recognized by laptop in bluetooth but not through jack
Recognized in bluetooth but won't connect anyway
Any advices ?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got it working by tricking around.

Had to enter the connection menu in bluetooth.
Then, quitted it.
Now, went in the bluetooth thing (B symbol) in the taskbar,
told it to connect, then it worked.
Put music on, switched the output (sound menu) to the device.
Shazam !!